# How to get store currency in cms blocks in magento2

Tags: magento2, cms, currency, cms-block

I have a CMS block which will be used in **multi-currency stores**.
I have a content,lets say "Grab it for `USD 100`".Now I want this to change based on **store currency selected**.How can i achieve this on **static block**.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can create the widget with the current currency and after that, you can use the widget on other textarea from admin.

Comment: Hi @St3phan thanks for the reply.Let me try this and reach you back.Thanks.

Comment: do you want me to do your widget or do you?

Comment: @St3phan,Yes please,You can do.I'm bit new for the Magento2

Comment: @St3phan I have created a widget for that.Currently the currency symbol is getting changed as per the store.But I want the amount to be changed.

Comment: you just wanted to currency, but where is the amount, is a TAX or what is it ?

Comment: @St3phan.Hi,Yeah I need to change the symbol and amount too.For example $1 to  ₹72 if I change the store view.But I have done that now.Thanks for your widget idea.

Comment: You must use from admin Stores -> Currency - > Currency Rates and after that, you can use the Currency  amount on the widget, and in the widget, you can add a new field with the custom default amount and you can create the formula for obtain the final result.